# Textarea cursor color in firefox

Tags: firefox, cursor, textarea, placeholder

I have a simple textarea in a page with a placeholder for when it is empty. I have styled the textarea in css to be white text and a transparent background. The body of my document is very dark so black text shows up poorly.  This all works fine in Chrome, IE, etc. However in firefox when the box is empty the placeholder text appears colored correctly, but when you click in the box (focus) the cursor starts out black until you start typing. If you delete what you typed, the placeholder text comes back and the cursor is black again. If you are not looking closely, it appears as if you clicked a control that is non-functional.

**How are people working around this?**

My CSS:

```
.statementInput {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color:white;
    border:none;
}
```

The text area line:

```
<textarea class="statementInput" id="st1" placeholder="Type something here"></textarea>
```

Comment: 27 views already but no answers? I get that it is a bug in Firefox, but how are people working around it? Certainly you aren't all just using white text areas?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, this is a bug that has [appeared in Firefox recently](https://support.mozilla.org/it/questions/936421) and [has been marked as a bug, too](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769405).

I have encountered this bug in my own work as well and I must say it's very frustrating. Unless somebody finds a workaround, I think we will just have to wait for the developers to release a new version of Firefox that fixes it.

Comment: For now I've ended up changing the textarea styling when the user clicks in it to edit (sad really)

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in at least Firefox ESR 31 and 36.
The following css snippet causes a white cursor on a dark background.

```js
.textInput:focus {
    color: white;
}
```

[Bug 830608](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=830608) states it has been fixed since 19.